# Observer on LiveData called before LoadInitial callback

Tags: observers, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

In a project that I'm working I'm using paginglibrary and retrofit. It's my first time doing that.

Data is returned normally. But I'm noticed the observer in my viewmodel, more precisely in my LiveData is called before the LoadIinitial callback in my PageKeyedDataSource. This makes the list passed to adapter empty.
Why Observer is called before my callback?

The ViewModel:

```
public GameDataViewModel(){
        GameResponseDataSourceFactory gameResponseViewModelFactory = new GameResponseDataSourceFactory();
        gameListLiveData = gameResponseViewModelFactory.getGameResponseMutableLiveData();

        PagedList.Config config = (new PagedList.Config.Builder())
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPageSize(20)
                .build();

        gameList = new LivePagedListBuilder(gameResponseViewModelFactory, config).build();
    }
```

This is when I call in my activity:

```
final GameListAdapter gameListAdapter = new GameListAdapter();

        GameDataViewModel gameDataViewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.
                getInstance(this.getApplication()).create(GameDataViewModel.class);

        gameDataViewModel.gameList.observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<GameResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable PagedList<GameResponse> gameResponses) {
                gameListAdapter.submitList(gameResponses);
            }
        });
```

My call on DataSource:

```
Call<GameListResponse> call = HttpConnectionHandler.getInstance().getTwitchGameApi().getTopGames(CLIENT_ID,  20, null,  null);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<GameListResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GameListResponse> call, Response<GameListResponse> response) {
                //initialLoading.postValue(DataState.SUCCESS);
                //networkState.postValue(DataState.SUCCESS);
                if(response.code() == 200) {
                    GameListResponse gameListResponse = response.body();
                    callback.onResult(gameListResponse.getGamesList(), 0, gameListResponse.getGamesList().size(), null, gameListResponse.getCursor());
                }
                else{
                    try {
                        Log.e("ERROR", response.errorBody().string());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

For my BIGGEST stupidity I was overriden getItemCount and returning zero.
Removing it, everything works fine.